# Parse HTML and find img tags within an <a> tag

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I need to parse HTML code and find all occurrences of `<img>` tags within an `<a>` tag to replace something in the `<a>` tag.

Let's say, I want to find

```
  <a ...><img src="path/to/image" /></a>
```

The `<a>` tag can contain different attributes and what I need to replace is:

`<a` by `<a class="something"`

The parsing is done in Python but I think, I will need the use of regular expressions.
However, I am pretty new to regular expressions so I am wondering how I can do this.

Comment: use BeautifulSoup or any other parser..Don't parse `HTML` with regex

Comment: About parsing HTML with Regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1771634

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks very good and is easy to use and fast...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the HTML isn't tricky (it complicates things when there seem to be tags within `<script>`s), it's pretty easy.

You can get the list of attributes from the `<a...>` with this regex:

`<a([^>]+)><img[^>]+></a>`

(If you find there may be spaces between things, you can use `<a([^>]+)>\s*<img[^>]+>\s*</a>`.)

It's really easy if you just need to add the one thing. You can use:

```
re.sub(r'<a([^>]+)><img([^>]+)></a>',
       r'<a' + ' class="something" ' + r'\1><img\2></a>',
       string)
```

In the above example, I use a second capture group to get `img`'s content.

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer

You should really use an [HTML parsing engine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) as there are many obscure edge cases that regex can't easily accommodate. But I'm not going to tell you how to live your life.

## Description

This regex will:

- find all the Anchor tags that wrap around IMG tags
- will match the opening `"<a "` so it can be replaced with `<a class=somevalue`
- avoid some really difficult edge cases

`(<a\b\s*)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\s?\/?>\s*<img\b\s*(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\s?\/?>\s*<\/a>)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the difficult edge case in the onmouseover attribute.

`<a onmouseover=' href="NotTheDroidYoureLookingFor" ; funRotator("<img href="not_the_droid_you_are_looking_for.png>") ; '  href="http://NotTheDroid.html">No droids here.
</a>
<a onmouseover=' href="Jedi_Mind_Trick.html" ; funRotator("<img href="not_the_droid_you_are_looking_for.png>") ; ' href="http://FoundTheDroid.html/"><img src="path/to/image/Desired_Droid.png" />
</a>`

**Python**

In python you could assign your sample text into a variable named `original_string` and issue the following line. Note the single quotes have been doubled up because the entire regex string is encased in a single quote.

`new_string = re.sub(r'(<a\b\s*)(?=(?:[^>=]|=''[^'']*''|="[^"]*"|=[^''"][^\s>]*)*?\s?\/?>\s*<img\b\s*(?:[^>=]|=''[^'']*''|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\s?\/?>\s*<\/a>)', r'<a class=FoundDroids ', original_string)`

**Results**

After the search and replace:

`<a onmouseover=' href="NotTheDroidYoureLookingFor" ; funRotator("<img href="not_the_droid_you_are_looking_for.png>") ; ' href="http://NotTheDroid.html">No droids here.
</a>
<a class=FoundDroids onmouseover=' href="Jedi_Mind_Trick.html" ; funRotator("<img href="not_the_droid_you_are_looking_for.png>") ; ' href="http://FoundTheDroid.html/"><img src="path/to/image/Desired_Droid.png" />
</a>`